# changes not occur in dart list when using copyWith

Tags: list, flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

Whenever the player pause I want to update the value isPlaying to false but that change not occur in list.

```
pause: (e) async* {
        await audioPlayer?.pause();

        yield state.copyWith(
          audioItems: AudioItems(
            audioItems: List<AudioItem>.from(state.audioItems.audioItems)
              ..firstWhere((element) => element.para == state.lastPlayingPara)
                  .copyWith(isPlaying: false),
          ),
        );
      }
```